# The best reason to close "primarily based on guesswork" questions

Tags: discussion

Recently, two questions were closed for different reasons:

- [Being addressed as “Anata” by a Japanese male friend](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66510/5010) (closed as "primarily opinion-based")
- [Tsunetero from tsundere](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66475/5010) (closed as "unclear what you're asking")

If I remember correctly, "too broad" has been used to close this kind of question, too. While I think questions like these can be closed, I also feel the reasons used to close them are not very spot-on.

- **"Primarily opinion-based"** is usually for questions like "Who is the best Japanese novelist?", but the questions mentioned above theoretically have one correct answer.
- **"Unclear what you're asking"** is mainly used for really poorly-written questions and non-questions.
- **"Too broad"** is usually for questions like "Tell me everything about kanji" or "I have 5 different questions about this paragraph".

So which is the best reason to close questions which meet the following criteria?

- What OP is asking for is clear, but the way to reach the correct answer is unclear.
- OP is expecting a short answer.
- Any answer will be a guess because of the lack of the context.
- OP is not willing to (or not able to) provide additional details.
- There is no way to verify if the answer is correct.

Or maybe we can add a "primarily speculative" or "insufficient context" close reason for this type of question? The description can be something like this:

> Please edit the question to include enough context. As it's currently written, any answer to this question will be a speculation, and it is impossible to verify its correctness.

Comment: "Insufficient context" sounds good to me. It is a stronger statement than "primarily speculative" because it tells you why it is speculative. Your example text looks spot on. It may need to be backed up by a comment as well as a close vote because it may not be obvious to the OP what context is missing.

Comment: @snailboat / other mods: is this something we have local control over? If so what sort of feedback/followup would you like to see on this meta post to make it happen? (And if we don’t have direct control, who is the right person to ping?)